# How can I use Material Design Lite with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-design-lite

I've been playing around with ReactJs and I'm needing to call `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` in each `componentDidMount()` handler.

Is there a way to not have to call `upgradeDom` on globally defined `componentHandler` and instead use webpack to import material design lite as a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this [discussion](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/833) on github but it doesn't look like the library will be upgraded soon to export `componentHandler`.

So instead I used the [exports-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exports-loader) plugin for webpack. My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony' },
        { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'exports-loader' }
    ]
},
```

This means that in my modules I can now call

```
var ch = require('exports?componentHandler!material-design-lite/material.js');
ch.upgradeDom();
```